# Use page layout for page with SharePoint 2010 in Visual Studio

Tags: page-layout, layouts

I have created a page layout with name: `TestLayout.aspx` in my solution.

After that I want the page`Home.aspx` to use this layout. How can I do that?

Comment: Why -1, this is popular question with a newbie like me.

Comment: u probably got the -1 because of the lack of information. try to be more descriptive of your scenario, sharepoint version (foundation vs server vs online, 2010 vs 2013) what exactly did you do so far, code vs designer approach, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
how to Change the Default Page Layout for Pages that are Created using “Add a Page” option in Site Actions of your SharePoint 2013 site. 
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/07/change-layout-of-an-existing-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I know this way. I mean "how to do it with sharepoint solution with visual studio".